# Impossible to display editor template for nested IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to display an Article with several fields in my view but it doesn't work right: the fields doesn't show (only the header (fields' names) does).

Article class:

```
public class Article : IComparable
{
    public IEnumerable<ArticleField> Fields
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [More properties...]
}
```

ArticleField class:

```
public class ArticleField
{
    // !! I want this display in a table Header !!
    [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Classes.ArticleField))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName="required", ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.Common.Validation))]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [More properties...]
}
```

Index.cshtml (appear fine to rendered html)

```
@model MygLogWeb.Classes.Article.Article

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Article", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table class="table">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @if (Model.IsSystem)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
                        @Model.Name
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsSystem)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsSystem)
                    @Model.IsSystem
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <br style="margin: 0.5em 0em;"/>

    @* POINT OF INTEREST *@
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fields, "ArticleFields") 

    <button type="submit" name="button" value="save">@Resources.Common.Buttons.save</button>
}
```

EditorTemplates/ArticleFields.cshtml (appear fine to rendered html)

```
@model IEnumerable<MygLogWeb.Classes.Article.ArticleField>

@using MygLogWeb.Classes.Article

@{
    var uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var GlobalViewBag = ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag;

    GlobalViewBag.ItemCount = Model.Count();
}

<table class="table none" id="@uid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsSystem)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsVirtual)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Formula)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @* POINT OF INTEREST *@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <input type="button" value="@Resources.Common.Buttons.add" data-row-add="ArticleField" data-row-addto="#@uid > TBODY" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    new TableEdit("@uid");
</script>
```

EditorTemplates/ArticleFields.cshtml (**doesn't appear at all to rendered html**)

```
@model MygLogWeb.Classes.Article.ArticleField

xxx
```

I though I could make `public IEnumerable<ArticleField> Fields` a `List<T>` but then I'll get an issue with the headers. Code such as `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Formula)` wouldn't work.

Comment: Something does not look right to me. In your `EditorTemplates/ArticleFields.cshtml` template you declare your model as an `IEnumerable` but you never iterate trough. Why so?

Comment: As far as I know, I cannot iterate. [] operator doesn't exist on IEnumerable and is required for properly named fields. So I have to let MVC handle the IEnumerable like it usually does fine when your main (Index.cshtml) model is an IEnumerable.

Comment: I can't, since EditorFor works only with the model and not custom (even similar) objects.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

You must use an element of the collection

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model[0])
```

or for loop over elements

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => item)
}
```

If you are planning to *post back* with the same model, then you'll want to use a `List` rather than an `IEnumerable` in order for the default model binder to create your objects in the post

Comment: 1) There no such operator for IEnumerable. 2) I need properly indexed fields name forach would break that.

Comment: I mentioned the header issue using List. If you have a nice workaround to that, it would help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your model to a list, iterate it and use `Editor` instead of `EditorFor`. Something along this line:

```
foreach(var entry in Model.ToList())
{
     Editor(entry, "ArticleFieldsItem");
}
```

And then create another template:

```
@model MygLogWeb.Classes.Article.ArticleField

<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsSystem)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsVirtual)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Formula)</td>
```

Comment: I would completely break the fields' names.

Comment: You are currently trying to have a template which automatically displays hierarchical data. It doesn't quite work that way. You can however break the levels apart. Have a template for a single `ArticleField` object and another for the entire `Fields` object. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did what I didn't want to, I completely stopped having IEnumerable properties in my models and use Arrays or Lists instead.

Then I of course could use for loops (not foreach ones) with [index].